# How to navigate git reflog in reverse order?

Tags: git, git-reflog

For `git log`, we have `git log --reverse` to navigate logs in the reverse order, but I tried `git reflog --reverse`, it returns `fatal: options '--reverse' and '--walk-reflogs' cannot be used together`. Is there any way to navigate `git reflog` in reverse order?

Comment: I was about to suggest `| tail -r` but the Git for Windows terminal seems not to recognize the `-r` option. (but `tac` works, so see [knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76578276/1057485)'s answer for people using Git for Windows)

Answer (score 1):

Most systems have `tac` available. Since the reflog is a flat list (and not a graph), you could simply reverse the list output:

```
git reflog | tac
```

Comment: `bash: tac: command not found` on macOS 13

Comment: @WenfangDu : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114041/how-can-i-get-the-tac-command-on-os-x -- looks like on MacOS `tail -r` does the same thing